# onTouch swipeup and swipedown all at once

Tags: android

I'm trying to do 3 things with my view. The first time my screen is "tapped" i want to totally set an ImageView on top of a view to 0alpha to show the beneath view. When the screen tap is lifted, I want the alpha back to 1alpha hiding the image. Next, while finger is down and the image is revealed, id like sliding up and down the screen to alter the alpha of the top layer so the beneath image is shown through it. My issue is I can't manage to parse swipeUp, swipeDown, and touch all at once, it's either only swipeUp and swipeDown, or only touch! Can someone help me hack my way around this ?

```
        blackPart.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {

            @Override
            public void onSwipeDown() {
                Log.d("OK", "bye");
                if(drawAlpha > 0.25)
                {
                    drawAlpha -= 0.25;

                };
                blackPart.setAlpha(drawAlpha);
                Log.d("notes", "alpha:" + drawAlpha);

            }
            @Override
            public void onSwipeUp() {
                if(drawAlpha < 1.0)
                {
                    drawAlpha += 0.25;
                }
                blackPart.setAlpha(drawAlpha);

            }


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
            {

                Log.d("notes", "touched");
                if(SP.getBoolean("drawingAlwaysVisible", false)) return true;

                    if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d("OK", "action up");
                    arg0.setAlpha(1.0f);
                }
                else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    arg0.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    Log.d("OK", "no");
                }

                return true;
            }


        });
```

Comment: You should return true in your if else statement, and change your existing return to false.

Comment: I just tried doing that, still no go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's part of code, which should work

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                    for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                        float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                        float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);

                        if (historicalY >= eventY) {
                            //move is down
                        } else {
                            //move is up
                        }
                        if (historicalX >= eventX) {
                            //move is right
                        } else {
                            //move is left
                        }
                        eventX = historicalX;
                        eventY = historicalY;

                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: X = " + eventX);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: Y = " + eventY);
                    }

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: in ACTION_MOVE... can u show me how to tell if it's moving Up or Down ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I did use something like this to move icon on the screens, so this should work.

Comment: I've added wrong comment in code, sorry. Let check in your code, does this work properly.